# Django - deployment with DigitalOcean issue - python collectstatic

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my django project, I've done all the process with gunicorn and nginx, I've arrived to the last line and I had to finally collect with "python manage.py collectstatic" when I get this error:

```
File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
```

here my manage.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'piattaforma.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

here my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for piattaforma project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '_j*f+(ceue_ff4hrgfk0l&r+)wrp@b8k2o4*snuenmuo$7yxib'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'accounts',
    'core',
    'quiz',
    'jobs',
    'emoji_picker',
    'ckeditor',

]

REGISTRATION_DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME="Students"

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'piattaforma.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/templates'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/templates'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'quiz/templates'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'jobs/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'piattaforma.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
# EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
# EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
# EMAIL_PORT = 587
# EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'MIO ACCOUNT'
# EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MIA PASSWORD'
# DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'IL MIO ACCOUNT GMAIL'
# DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = 'TO EMAIL'

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/


STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= '/'
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve it? thank you

NB: I added STATIC_ROOT = '/home/mattia/static-serve/'
from nano settings.py

Answer (score 0):

you probably have something wrong in the settings.py, check if you have set up STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS correctly

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I uploaded the settings.py, it seems correct but for sure i'm missing something